# How to obtain the number of records of a dataset in SAS

Tags: sas, dataset

I want to count the number of records in a `dataset` in `SAS`. There is a function the make this thing in a simple way? I used `R` ed for obtain this information there was the `length()` function. Morover I need the number of record to compute some percetages so I need this value not in a table but in a value that can be used for other `data step`. How can I fix?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you Googled 'count number of records in a SAS dataset'?

Comment: If you're using it to compute percentages, you probably DO want this value in a dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another solution, using SAS dictionaries,

```
proc sql;
    select nobs into: num_obs
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname = "WORK" and memname = "A"
    ;
quit;
```

It is easy to get the size of many datasets by modifying the above code,

```
proc sql;
    create table test as
    select memname, nobs
    from dictionary.tables
    where libname = "WORK" and memname like "A%"
    ;
quit;
data _null_;
    set test;
    call symput(memname, nobs);
run;
```

The above code will give you the sizes of all data sets with name starting with "a" in the temporary/work library.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is a basic SAS table that you've created, and not modified or appended to, the best way is to use the meta data held in a dataset (the Number of tries is held in a piece of meta data called "nobs"), without reading through the dataset its self and place it in a macro variable. You can do this in the following way:

```
Data _null_;
 i=1;
 If i = 0 then set DATASETTOCOUNT nobs= mycount;
Call symput('mycount', mycount);
Run;

%put &mycount.;
```

You will now have a macro variable that contains the number of rows in your dataset, that you can call on in other data steps using &mycount.